# iOS Swift: UITableViewCell editing set true after row deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

After deleting a row in a UITableView the next row I create has editing set to true. I'm not sure why this is, but what it means is that after I delete a row, the next row that I create is [indented on the left side by about 40 points](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewd5jpny1o4fj1w/Screenshot%202015-03-08%2014.44.37.png?dl=0).

Do I need to set the table or the cell to `editing = false` after I remove a cell?

```
func removeItems(items: [CKRecord], indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    for item in items {
        db.deleteRecordWithID(item.recordID) { (record, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                if let index = find(exercises, item) {
                    exercises.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    days.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: Adding `cell.editing = false` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` solves it, but it seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently deleting a row doesn't disable editing for that row. I added this line before `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` which seems to do the trick:

`tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.setEditing(false, animated: false)`

My understanding is that when I swipe on a cell I'm enabling editing for that cell. And because the next cell I insert is at the same index it's being drawn with editing enabled.